# Action works only after random # of tries

Tags: php, symfony

I'm a little confused why my `removeAction` only works after a random number of attempts. Sometimes it works after 4 or 5 clicks and others it works right away.

The button is meant to simply remove an item from the users cart. I get the product id from the cart and use then use `remove()` and `flush()` to update the database. Like I said, it works but only after a random number of tries. Why is that? My logic seems sound but clearly something is wrong but I can't figure it out.

If I dump `$quantity` or `$cart` I see the correct product id every time before I use `remove()`

`removeAction function`:

```
/**
 * Removes a 'product' from the cart
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/remove", name="product_remove")
 * @METHOD("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function removeAction(Request $request, $id) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $product = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:Product')->find($id);

    $cart = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:UserCart')->findOneBy(['user' => $this->getUser(), 'submitted' => false]);

    $quantity = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:Quantity')->findOneBy(['product' => $product->getId()]);
                                            //get product id from the cart and then remove it

// product gets removed but only after a random # of click on the remove button...



    // dump($quantity);
    // dump($cart);


    $em->remove($quantity);
    $em->flush();

    $this->addFlash('notice', 'The product: '.$product->getName().' was removed!');

    return $this->redirectToRoute('product_showCart');
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: how are you verifying if the removal worked? are you querying the db directly? if you're verying through the app, then make sure all caching (client & server) is disabled

Comment: The product goes away in the users cart in my database, also the flash notice shows when it works. But like I said, after only a random number of tries

Comment: Check if the script times out while calling the `remove` method.

Comment: @web-nomad please excuse my lack of knowledge but, how do I do that?

Comment: Please check if the time taken in the method is greater than the `max_execution_time` ini setting.

Comment: I'm new to web development, I googled how to do what you asked but can't get it working, could you tell me how?

Comment: the `max_execution_time` is 30 and I dumped `microtime()` to check the run time of the method and it's `float(0.0133440494537)`